# How do I access a certain string in a char double pointer?

Tags: c

I am creating a program that needs to read in an arbitrary amount of lines of arbitrary length each (but for now assuming one string per line). So basically, I need a dynamic array of dynamic string. I figured the easiest way to do this would be with a char double pointer. But I am getting errors with the asprintf statement. particularly "strings[track]". I figured this would point to the first char array. Any help on how to do this?

Here is the code so far:

```
char **strings;

int readFile(char* filename)
{
        FILE *fp;

        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
                return -1;
        }
        char *singleLine = NULL;
        ssize_t lineSize;
        size_t amount = 0;
        int track = -1;
        while((lineSize = getline(&singleLine, &amount, fp)) != -1)
        {   
                track++;
                asprintf(&strings[track],"%s",singleline));
        }
}
```

Comment: What specific errors are you getting?  Did you try reading them and making sense of them first?  Please post them here.  Also, please post a [mcve] so we can see how you allocated memory for the strings, and anything else that might matter.

Comment: This assumes that you've allocated enough memory in `strings` -- you might first need `strings = realloc(strings, sizeof(*strings) * (track+1))`

Comment: @Barmar That would cause all kinds of problems - if `getline()` makes a call to `realloc()`, the previous entry would be invalid, and if `getline()` doesn't `realloc()`, the previous line will be overwritten.  `strings[track] = strdup( singleline );` would work, though.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yeah, I write that comment before I noticed this was in a loop using the same `singleLine` variable. Another solution would be to set `singleLine` back to `NULL` before each call to `getLine()`.

Comment: The code in the question never allocates space for `strings`. Before you store points in it, you must allocate space for them, and `asprintf(&strings[track],"%s",singleline));` does not do that; it merely updates `strings[track]` after you have provided memory for the pointers that `strings` must point to. Fix that. If it is insufficient, edit the question to provide a [mre]. Also, using `asprintf` to duplicate strings is inefficient. Use `strdup`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You didn't see Barmer's original comment before he edited it...

Comment: @Andrew: You should delete comments that are no longer applicable.

Comment: About allocating memory, that is what asprintf is for. asprintf itself allocates memory large enough for the string including the null terminating.

Comment: I get a segmentation fault pointing at the asprintf line. I also tried strdup and same error. Anyone have any better methods?